# Что удалили в базе данных MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет. Возможно глупый вопрос, но я им не владею. Делал сайт, ещё не знаю как сделать слежку за изменениями данными в базе. У нас было 169 объектов, пользователи удалили 2 из них. Как узнать какие именно строки в базе данных были удалены. В данном случае в таблице "board". Мне надо понимать почему человек удалил объекты. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение данной задачи может лежать в разных плоскостях. Всё зависит от детализации информации о удалённых данных.

1. Самый простой вариант это добавление признака удаления для строки. Дополнительное поле is_deleted. И в коде на запрос пользователя не удалять физически данные, а проставлять флаг о удалении. Плюсы - простота в реализации, минусы - со временем нужно чистить базу от старых ненужных данных.
2. Создать вторую таблицу например board_archive, а для основной таблицы board привязать триггер на удаление, в котором реализовать логику копирования удалённых данных из board в board_archive. Возможно не всех данных, только какую-то общую информацию. Всё зависит от вашей задачи. Плюсы - основная рабочая таблица не замусоривается, минусы - сложнее в реализации и также требует со временем сборки мусора.
3. Записывать информацию об удаляемых данных на уровне кода, логирование и т.д. Плюсы - вы полностью управляете процессом сохранения информации об удаляемых данных, минусы - сложнее в реализации.
4. Если нужен анализ данных то возможно нужно отойти от традиционных crud базы данных и посмотреть в сторону event sourcing. Плюсы - сохраняется вся информация о поведении пользователя. Минусы - сложно в реализации.

Для начала можно выбрать 2 вариант, и сохранять только метаданные удаляемых записей. Потом время от времени по планировщику удалять старые данные.

Но в любом случае нужно выбирать под задачу.

Answer (score 4):

Ну я бы сделал вообще не удаление, а просто скрытие для клиентов объекта. Например, сделать столбик delete_status если стоит 0, то данные показываются, если 1, то данные не показываются. Это просто и себя подстрахуете.

Comment: Хорошая идея. Но в таком случае весь массив остаётся на сервере (текст, фотки и т.д.) и сама запись среди общего потока строк вместе с рабочими. Мне надо знать просто наименования этого объекта, его id и какой пользователь.

Comment: ну тогда просто сделать еще одну базу, где будут храниться данные удаленных объектов ну и id пользователя который совершил действие.

Comment: @dolphinbibik ну и что что остается? Скажу тебе по секрету, когда ты в БД удаляешь запись, она тоже не физически удаляется, а только помечается как удаленная. И лежит "вместе с рабочими". И никому это не мешает.

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на [триггеры](https://habrahabr.ru/post/37693/). Мы на Oralce делали так же, чтобы отследить что именно удаляли из таблиц

Answer (score 2):

Надо понимать, что операция удаления означает полное выведение информации из системы. Если Вы хотите хранить каким-либо образом информацию об удаленных данных, делайте это явно. К примеру сделав логгирование запросов к БД из приложения или воспользовавшись инструментами самой базы. Ну или в крайнем случае помечайте файлы как удаленные, не удаляя их из системы на самом деле.

Для приложения поищите подходящие инструменты логгирования в зависимости от используемых инструментов разработки CMS/Framework/etc и прикрутите.

Для MySQL это называется [бинарные логи](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html), вот еще [информация с хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/22772/). Но журналы могут быть сложны при разборе и лучше все-таки обзавестись логгером.

P.S. Ну или придется поднимать дампы и их просматривать.